# Implementing In-App Purchases in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

here is my html code

```
   <html>
    <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function testInapp(){
      console.log("Inside in app");

inAppPurchase.getProducts(['myapp.xyz']).then(function(products){
      console.log(products);
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});

var restorePurchases = function(){
  inAppPurchase.restorePurchases().then(function(data){
    if(data.productId === 'myapp.xyz'){

    }else if(data.productId === 'myapp.xyze'){

    }
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
};

var purchase = function(productId){
  inAppPurchase.buy(productId).then(function(data){
    if(data.productId=== 'myapp.xyz'){


    }else if(data.productId === 'myapp.xyzs'){

    }

    purchases
    return inAppPurchase.consume(data.type, data.receipt, data.signature);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
};


    }


  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <input type="button" value="IN-APP" onclick="testInapp()"/>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here on click of button m calling the testInapp() function which contains the In-App Purchases code But I'm getting `inAppPurchase is not defined`
Here is the  plugin which I'm using `https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase` can anybody help me to find out where i doing wrong

Comment: run in CLI: `$ cordova plugin list`. Be sure you installed plugin properly

Comment: @MaximShoustin on running `cordova plugin list ` its shows cordova-plugin-inapppurchase 1.1.0 "In App Purchase"

Comment: How did this particular plugin end up working for you?

Comment: @RobertGarcia Yes It is working fine now

Comment: @gauravsingh why don`t you share with us what you find out to be the solution ?